# Set Value to a text box having unique id using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've a textbox with ID something like this

```
ADF_ADF3_DET0fe90e140MmM10d0%5478
```

In that ADF_ADF3_DET is fixed, and the rest information is appended and it will be changing. How can I set some value to this text box using jQuery? If the textbox has ADF_ADF3_DET, I need to set? Any ideas?

Comment: try with `$("[id^=ADF_ADF3_DET]").val("yourvalue")` please not that it will set it for all that has an id starting with `ADF_ADF3_DET`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, please put that in answer. Will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `^=` selector, this means it will use all the starts with a specific string

```
$("[id^=ADF_ADF3_DET]").val("yourvalue")
```

**Demo**

```js
$("[id^=ADF_ADF3_DET]").val("yourvalue")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ADF_ADF3_DET0fe90e140MmM10d0%5478" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/ctqa7s9n/

```js
$('input[id^= ADF_ADF3_DET]').val('1224');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ADF_ADF3_DET0fe90e140MmM10d0%5478">
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Shiladitya.. Carsten was a bit early :)

Answer (score 1):

You can select by matching the start of the id like this:

`$('[id^="ADF_ADF3_DET"]').doSomeThing(...)`

The above will select every element on the page as long as the ID starts with ADF_ADF3_DET.

Another approach would be to add the 'changing data' to a data attribute.

`$('#ADF_ADF3_DET').data('attrname', '0fe90e140MmM10d0%5478');`

The latest will enable you to select the element with the same css selector, no matter what data is in the data attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Other than ADF_ADF3_DET will be auto generated and it will change.

Comment: You can print data attributes with server side language in html `<input data-attrname="loremipsum" ... >` (attrname is a name you can choose)

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
// var id = "ADF_ADF3_DET" + $('').val() or value; //your value lik 0fe90e140MmM10d0%5478
var id = "ADF_ADF3_DET" + "0fe90e140MmM10d0%5478";


$('#' + id).val('text'); //done your code
```